# Wikipedia read-only bot API?

Tags: bots, wikipedia

I have written my own read-only bot (in Objective C) that simply does a curl of target pages every six seconds; it works fine, but takes days when I need to read thousands of pages.  So I'd like to switch to a bot API to set maxlag=5 to get better performance when the load is low.  Can you point me to the *appropriate* description of how to write such a simple read-only bot?  I have found only complicated descriptions of how to write, e.g., editing bots.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is as simple as adding "&maxlag=5" to the end of my current curl request.  I'm trying it now...

Comment: Nope, not that simple.

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions.
Specify pages by pageids or titles. If your specific pages have something in common (template, image, category) you can use a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators)